# How would I await for a new message, after the first message being a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Currently, I am using Discord.Js to create a bot.
I want to create a semi-sentence generator.
What it does, is it presents you with a random sentence to fill in, eg, I like ----- because of -----.
then it waits for a new message, that new message becomes var1 and var1 is the first line of unfilled sentence, then it waits for a second, new message, that second new message becomes var2, and var2 is the second line of unfilled dots. Every time I run the command, all it does is take the first message and runs it as the original command.

```js
} else if(message.content ==='*testcreate') {
        message.channel.send('Finish the sentance!');
        message.channel.send('I like ----- because of -----');
        var thingbegin = await message
        var thing1 = args[0].substr(1)
        message.channel.send('Now what do you want the second one to say?')
        var thingawait = await thing1
        var thing2 = args[0].substr(1)
        var thingawait2 = await thing2
        message.channel.send('I like '+ thing1 +' because of '+ thing2 +'');
    }
```

The output comes out as:

```
Finish the sentance!
I like ----- because of -----
I like testcreate because of testcreate
```

instead of the wanted outcome, any help?

Comment: Why are you awaiting all this? None of these variables are promises.

Comment: It awaits for 2 different messages, the first being the first variable, the second being the second